# Error for a program _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK)

Tags: c++

This is a question from a book and I am getting the following error:
_free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK)

Below is the code for the implementation of a class:

```
template<class T>
Set<T>::Set(): items(NULL), num_items(0)
{
}

template<class T>
Set<T>::Set(const Set<T>& other)
{
    num_items = other.num_items;
    items = other.to_array();
}

template<class T>
Set<T>::~Set()
{
    if (items != NULL)
    {
        delete[] items;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Set<T>::operator= (const Set<T>& right_side)
{
    if (items != NULL)
    {
        delete[] items;
    }
    num_items = right_side.num_items;
    items = right_side.to_array();
}

template<class T>
void Set<T>::add(T item)
{
    if (!contains(item))
    {
        T *new_items = new T[num_items + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < num_items; i++)
        {
            new_items[i] = items[i];
        }
        new_items[num_items] = item;
        if (num_items > 0)
        {
            delete[] items;
        }
        num_items++;
        items = new_items;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Set<T>::remove(T item)
{
    if (contains(item))
    {
        T *copy = NULL;
        if (num_items > 1)
        {
            copy = new T[num_items - 1];
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < num_items; i++)
            {
                if (items[i] != item)
                {
                    copy[j] = items[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        delete[] items;
        items = copy;
        num_items--;
    }
}

template<class T>
int Set<T>::size() const
{
    return num_items;
}

template<class T>
bool Set<T>::contains(T item) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_items; i++)
    {
        if (items[i] == item)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
T *Set<T>::to_array() const
{
    T *copy = NULL;
    if (num_items > 0)
    {
        copy = new T[num_items];
        for (int i = 0; i < num_items; i++)
        {
            copy[i] = items[i];
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

I looked up the issue and I believe it is the delete[] part that is causing this issue.
Can someone tell me what the error is and how do i rectify this?

Comment: Could you please post the full implementation of the Set class?

Comment: It is the full implementation?

Below is the main file:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Set.cpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace myset;

template<class T>
void output_set(Set<T> myset)
{
 T *ptr = myset.to_array();
 if (ptr != NULL)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < myset.size(); i++)
   cout << ptr[i] << endl;
  delete[] ptr;
 }
 else
 {
  cout << "The set is empty." << endl;
 }
}

int main()
{
 Set<int> int_set;
 int_set.add(3);
 int_set.add(4);
 cout << "Contents of int_set:" << endl;
 output_set(int_set);
 return 0;
}

Comment: I would prefer one that can be copy and pasted and compiled. The code you have posted does not contain the class declarations.

Comment: I've just viewed your edited comment. I see that you are including headers. Please include your **"Set.h"** header file in the post. You have only posted the "Set.cpp" file - this file only contains the function definitions, not the declarations of functions or variables.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include "Set.h"

namespace myset
{
 //The above pasted code of the implementation file goes here
}

Comment: Definition of the interface file:
#ifndef _SET_H
#define _SET_H

namespace myset
{
 template <class T>
 class Set
 {
 public:
  Set();
  Set(const Set<T>& other);
  ~Set();
  void operator= (const Set<T>& right_side);
  void add(T item);
  void remove(T item);
  int size() const;
  bool contains(T item) const;
  T *to_array() const;

 private:
  T *items;
  int num_items;
 };
}

#endif

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've solved the problem.

Replace the `contains` function in `Set.cpp` with:

```
template<class T>
bool Set<T>::contains(T item) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_items; i++)
    {
        if (items[i] == item)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then for your `print_set` function in `main.cpp` replace with this:

```
template<class T> 
 void output_set(Set<T> myset) 
 { 
   T *ptr = myset.to_array(); 
   if (ptr != NULL) 
   { 
    for (int i = 0; i < myset.size(); i++) {
      cout << ptr[i] << endl;  } 
   }
   else { 
     cout << "The set is empty." << endl;
    } 
}
```

**Explanation**

In the `contains` function, you forgot to return `false` when the `item` was not found. This meant that the function returned no value in this case, and when you called this function while adding an item to the `Set` for the `if` statement checking there was an item, this failed.

Now for the `print_set` function, you deleted the `ptr` each time in the loop even though you did not finish printing, so the first item was printed correctly, but the remaining items did not.

Comment: Note that failing to return a value from a non-void function is Undefined Behavior - anything may happen.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - and this caused the runtime error. I have also just noticed that the "to_array" method of the Set class may also fail to return a value despite being non-void - this happens when there are no items in the Set.

The potential no-return values are usually picked up by a good compiler or IDE with dynamic syntax checking - I know VC++ and VS does it. I'm not 100% sure, but I think with -Wall, g++ and clang will also detect these potential errors.